# Selenium with SWFUpload

Tags: testing, selenium, upload, automation, swfupload

I tried to use Selenium for the automation testing script. The testing web page used SWFUpload for uploading. I don't see any api in Selenium to resolve the upload.

Here is the page: http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/multiinstancedemo/index.php

I found flash-selenium but it is not useful.

http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/

Thanks,
Jame

Answer (score 1):

One way of uploading documents is by using autoscripts.
However, autoit scripts are only supported on a windows machine.
You need to do following:

1. Click on browse button.
2. Run the `.exe` autoit file.(exe file can be converted from autoit scripts).